# Windows service exits with code 0 and no errors even though it hasn't done its thing

Tags: c#, json, windows, api, service

I have a windows service that calls a web API service.  All the API calls have been tested and work as they should.

What happens is the service runs a particular piece of code that sends data to the API.  Its supposed to return and continue round the loop.  What it does is just stop.  The JSon has been sent to the API with fiddler and works fine.

Here is the offending code :-

```
public async Task<WorkOrderCreationResponseDto> ImportWorkOrders(WorkOrderCreationRequestDto request)
    {
        try
        {

            WorkOrderCreationResponseDto resp = await RestClient.PostAsync<WorkOrderCreationRequestDto, WorkOrderCreationResponseDto>(string.Format("{0}/WorkOrders", Resource), request);

            return resp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

Now the code gets to the await line.  At this point the code exits with code 0.  It never hits the return and no error is trapped in the catch.

Can anyone explain why this happens as I am at a complete loss after a morning trolling round google trying to make sense of it all.

Anything that can shed some light on this would be greatly appreciated.

The environment is Windows 10 anniversary update and Visual Studio 2015.  We are coding in c#.

Thanks
Steve

**ADDED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**

We build a data object which is wo in the code below.  _rest contains the user credentials for the API.

```
using (SopImportDataService service = new SopImportDataService(_rest))
                            {
                                string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wo);

                                //WorkOrderCreationResponseDto c = await service.ImportWorkOrders(wo);

                                await service.ImportWorkOrders(wo);

                                Console.WriteLine("");
                            }
```

Comment: How is `ImportWorkOrders` called?

Comment: Hi Glorin,  Ive added an other code snippet to the question.

Comment: Perhaps I should have approached it differently:it sounds like something is not getting awaited somewhere up the call stack and that your program is exiting as soon as your async method yields the current thread.

Comment: Just so its clear in my head, and believe me that can be a scary place,  if I work backwards from the point it stops there may be a missing await on a call somewhere?

Comment: That'd be my guess from the description. The likely place would be your main loop. If you missed a wait/await, then as soon as one of your async methods yields the thread, your main loop will pick up as if your async method had finished. If this allows your program to meet its exit condition, then you could very well see the program exit with no errors but never having completed the async call.

Comment: It seems the secret this is to get my OnStart to behave in an Asynchronous way even though services are synchronous by nature

Comment: In non-GUI apps you can use `Task.Wait()` at your highest level, i.e. in your main loop, to block while awaiting the result of the async chain.

Comment: @MagicWand: I'm not sure what you mean by saying that services are synchronous in nature, but keep in mind that OnStart() is expected to return promptly.  If you need a main loop it should be in a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks to Glorin for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Harry - thanks for the response.  Yes we have a main loop running in its own thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Glorin for pointing me in the right direction.  The problem was Main in the Progrm.cs file is not Async.  We have used the AsyncEx library by Stephen Cleary, and altered the program.cs to look like this :-

```
static class Program
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
#if (!DEBUG)
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new UnityService()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
 #else
        UnityService myServ = new UnityService();
        //myServ.SetupService().ConfigureAwait(true);

        await myServ.BeginService();
#endif
    }
```

These changes seem to have solve dour issue.

Thanks again everyone